# RavenDb NoSQL many to many modeling

Tags: nosql, ravendb

I'm new to NoSQL databases (RavenDb) and I would want to know which is the best way to model the following situation:

I am doing a booking calendar for medical consultations. There are several types of medical consultations based on medical specialty and type of consultation (first or subsecuent). 
So for example, a first medical consultation of cardiology takes 30min and a subsecuent one 15min. Each specialty has its duration.

The problem comes when there are some doctors whose consultation time is different from the general. So, usually, a first cardiology consultation takes 30min, but when the doctor is John the Rapid it only takes 20min.

For this cases we used to have a table relating consultation types with these rare doctors with the special duration inside. So we made a left join with this table and if there was a record for this type of consultation and selected doctor, we applyed the time in this table. If there wasn't a record, we took the standard value of consultation type.

Should I continue using this approach and querying another collection to see if there are different timings, or is better to include this info in the collection of consultation types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply create a 'Doctors' collection where each document can be like:

```
{ 
    "Name": "John the Rapid",
    "speciality": "Cardiaology",
    "FirstConsultationTime": "20",
    "SecondConsultationTime": "10",
    .....
}
```

and that's it.

Optionally, for 'regular' doctors, 
you can create skinnier documents within this **same** collection that look like:

```
{ 
    "Name": "Some other name",
    "speciality": "Cardiaology",
    .....
}
```

and when you query for the doctor, 
 if the 'time' field doesn't exist then you use some default value (30 min, and 15 min) ...

You may want to read:
https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/3-document-modeling#document-modeling

Comment: Consultation type should be a collection on its own because it's used in several places

Comment: Although, I could add a reference of the consultation type to doctor object with different timings for different types of consultation I think it will be better the other way. Add doctor and timing to consultation type. This is because of the application operation. When you are going to book a consultation, usually you search, for eaxample, for a cardiology first consultation, the app searchs in all cardiology calendars without the need to load doctors. Thanks for your answer, it helped me taking the decission of embedding the needing info in a document instead of creating a new collection

Comment: With your first approach - you can use 'related documents' - 
and the document field would look something like:
"FirstConsultationTime": "consultationTimes/2-A".
(where consultationTimes/2-A" refers to a document in another collection.)
Learn more about related documents in: https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/create-related-documents